# postgres: when index is used

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

just to better understand in which cases index is correctly used i would like to enumerate possible cases.

let's assume we have a table with "a", "b", "c", "d" columns.

we create an index on (a, b, c, d):

```
create index my_index on table my_table (a, b, c, d)
```

is it used when:

1)

```
where a=% and b=% and c=% and d=%
```

2)

```
where a=% and b=%
```

3)

```
where a=%
```

4)

```
where b=% and c=% and d=%
```

5)

```
where c=% order by b
```

6)

```
where a=% and b=% and c=% order by case when d is not null then d else c end
```

7)
let's assume now we have more column for the 7 point but the index only on (a, b, c, d)

```
where a=% and b=% and c=% and d=% and e=% and f=% and g=%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has pretty good [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) explaining multi-column indexes.  The rules are basically the same across databases (although there is some more advanced stuff).

Of course, there are other factors -- such as what is going on in the `from` clause, what columns are being selected, statistics about the tables, and so on.

The following is basic guidance:

1) `where a=% and b=% and c=% and d=%`

Yes, as long as all the conditions are equality.  I don't know what happens with collation conflicts.

2) where a=% and b=%

Yes, as long as all the conditions are equality.  I don't know what happens with collation conflicts.

3) where a=%

Yes, as long as all the conditions are equality.  I don't know what happens with collation conflicts.

4) where b=% and c=% and d=%

Probably not.  If used, the index would need to be scanned.  This would be the case if the index covered the query.

5) where c=% order by b

Probably not.

6) where a=% and b=% and c=% order by case when d is not null then d else c end

Should be used for the `where` clause.  A sort will still be needed.

Comment: It also depends on the distribution of the values, if a only has 2 possible values and there are thousands or millions of records where a = % might not lead to the usage of the index.